# Cálculo com Matrizes em R

Tags: r

Quais funções eu devo usar para fazer os seguintes cálculos com matrizes no R:
- Achar a matriz transposta;
- Achar a matriz inversa;
- Achar a matriz identidade;
- Achar o determinante de uma matriz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sendo M sua matriz,

- Transposta `t(M)`
- Inversa `solve(M)`
- Identidade `diag(x = 1, nrow, ncol)`
- Determinante `det(M)`

Comment: Isso vem no R-intro.pdf: transposta secção 5.6; identidade 5.7.1; inversa 5.7.2; determinante 5.7.4. E, claro, muito mais.